# How can I deploy a application written in c++?

Tags: c++, deployment

A couple of weeks ago I wrote a game in c++ used dev compiler to run the code, Now I am looking forward to deploying it .what are the steps I must follow

Comment: "deploy" is pretty broad. How do you want to deploy it?

Comment: well i want to publish it like all the other games available on the internet

Answer (score 0):

1. make a release output and test it
2. determine what dependencies
   are required. (vcredist, .Net, dxsdk, ...)
3. test your application
   on some computer rather than your development computer ( and test if
   any other dependencies are needed.)
4. create the setup package using
   a setup creator (Inoo Setup, advanced installer , ... , just an apk
   for android ...)
5. test your setup.

Comment: using the free edition of Advance Installer http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html